# My Session is not working on home page after login

Tags: php, session-variables

I have been trying to get session to carry over to my home page from my index page which have my login form but keep kicking back to index page. I have no idea whats is wrong, i check that session_start() is on both page. Need help badly and any help will be greatly appreciated.

index.php script:

```
`<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 session_start();

 if(isset($_COOKIE['loginMemPro'])) 
 {
 include_once("Connections/first.php");

  $memEmail = $_COOKIE['loginMemPro']['memEmail'];  
  $password = $_COOKIE['loginMemPro']['log_password'];

    $query = "SELECT email, password FROM pro_members WHERE email = '$memEmail' AND   
     password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) 
{
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;  
$_SESSION['loginMem'] = $memEmail;
header('Location: http://www.pro.com/home.php');
exit();
}
    }
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link href="/image/x-con.png" rel="icon" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="userlogin_form" name="userlogin_form" action="login_process.php" 
     method="post">
     <table width="100%">
      <tr>
      <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="20%">
                    <span id="sprytextfield5">
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A email address is required.</span><span 
       class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid email address format.</span><br/>
       Email
          <input name="memEmail" type="text" id="memEmail" value="" size="30" />
          </span></td>
        <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
          <span id="sprylog_password">
          <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A password is required.</span><br/>
          Password
            <input name="log_password" type="password" id="log_password" value="" 
          size="30" />
          </span></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>               
        <label for="memberMe">
          <input name="memberMe" type="checkbox" id="memberMe" value="setcookie" />
          Remember Me</label>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="login" value="login" />  
      </td>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td align="right">
        <a id="forgotpw_link_id" class="forgotpw_link" href="">forgot password?</a>
        </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       </body>
       </html>`
```

home.php script:

```
   `<?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path .= "/login_auth.php";
      include_once($path);?>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
         $path .= "/CSS/home_style.css";
     include_once($path);?>


      <body class="thrColLiq" onload="MM_preloadImages">

     <div id="header">
       <?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     $path .= "/header.php";
     include_once($path);?>
      <!-- end #mainContent -->
        </div>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar1">
       <?php
      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
      $path .= "/leftside_bar.php";
     include_once($path);?>
     </div>  
    <div id="sidebar2">
    <?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/rightside_bar.php";
     include_once($path);?>
     </div>

     <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order 
     to force the #container div to contain all child floats -->
<div id="mainContent">
  <!-- end #mainContent -->
      <?php
       $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path .= "/menu.php";
       include_once($path);?>
      < /div>
   <div id="mainContent2">
         <?php
       $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/home_script.php";
     include_once($path);?>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent3">
  <!-- end #mainContent -->
      <?php
       $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
       $path .= "/footer.php";
      include_once($path);?>
      </div>
  <br class="clearfloat" />
      <!-- end #container -->
       </div>
     </body>
     </html>
      `
```

login auth.php script:

```
    `<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
     session_start();

     if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {        
      header('Location: http://www.pro.com/index.php?error=1');
     exit();                    
     }
     ?>
     `
```

login_process.php script:

```
     `<?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        session_start();            
       include_once("Connections/first.php");
      $memEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memEmail']); 
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['log_password']);


       $time = time();                  
      $check = $_POST['memberMe'];              

      $query = "SELECT email, password FROM pro_members WHERE email = '$memEmail' AND    
       password = '$password'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {     
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;    
  $_SESSION['loginMem'] = $memEmail;
  if($check) {      
  setcookie("loginMemPro[memEmail]", $memEmail, $time + 3600);    
  setcookie("loginMemPro[log_password]", $password, $time + 3600);  
  }

      header('Location: http://www.pro.com/home.php');
      exit(); 
     }
     else
    {
     header('Location: http://www.pro.com/index.php?error=1');
     exit();
     }
     ?>`
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: how does that help session carry over to next page

Comment: comments are for additional suggestions to improve your code etc- answers are for helping the question :P

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools and fix the formattings of the code you've got in your question. Also this is not a debugging forum, please see http://sscce.org/ and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php has no `session_start();` But you need to check your error logs and tell us if there is any errors..your error reporting is only going to show errors in  certain circumstances rather than cover all circumstances because its not the first line of your php scripts.

See here:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;  
$_SESSION['loginMem'] = $memEmail;
```

Because theres no session_start(); before these two theres no way these can be created..

Index does not include `login auth.php` or `login_process.php` so im not seeing where session_start is on index.php ?

Side note: `Don't use mysql_*` !!

Comment: it is in the script forget it on here

Comment: Can you show it in the script because i can't see any thing wrong so far.. also have you checked your php error log file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session_start(); on every page on top. Only after that session will work.

If still session is not creating, check the session setting in php.ini

To you sessions you have to set or reset following parameter in your php.ini file

```
Define path to save sessions
session.save_path = "C:\php\sessiondata\"

Whether to use cookies.
session.use_cookies = 1 

To Initialize session on request startup.
Set session.auto_start = 1

Name of the session (used as cookie name).
session.name = PHPSESSID

Define Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

;The path for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_path = /

The domain for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_domain =

 Handler used to serialize data. php is the standard serializer of PHP.
session.serialize_handler = php
```

There are some more setting which may be used to modify your Sessions. For more  Details refer php.ini
support manually in each page script:
 Call session_start() function.

Comment: don't see a php.ini file in my directory

Comment: you will find that in your php installation directory. search for php.ini file